# Show that a continuous function zero for all rationals is zero everywhere.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification, continuity

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and that $f(r) = 0 \ \forall r \in \mathbb{Q}$. Prove that $f(x) = 0 \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

I believe I have a proof of this, but I am hoping to confirm it because I found myself using the argument in other similar problems.

I have:

$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ s.t. whenever $y \in B_{\delta}(x), f(y) \in B_{\epsilon}(f(x))$

Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, every ball around a rational contains irrationals. So, whenever

$|r - y| < \delta, |f(r) - f(y)| = |f(y)| < \epsilon$

So, $f(y) = 0$ and $y$ is arbitrary.

Take the union of all of the balls center at the rationals. This is open since the union of open balls is open. Since the rationals are dense, this union is equal to all of $\mathbb{R}$. So, this holds $\forall y$.

Is this a possible argument? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I  feel your statements are unclear because it is unclear how you set the variables $r,y,\epsilon,\delta$. (I think "every ball around a rational contains irrationals" is not important, and "every ball around any irrational contains rationals" is more important.)

Comment: This is true for any dense set, not just the rationals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach could be by sequences. Since $f$ is contnuous and using the density of ir rationals  for every $r$ irracional there exists $x_n\in \mathbb{Q}$ $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ such as $x_n\to r$ as $n\to\infty$. So $f(r) =\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty} 0=0$

Comment: I was just about to write up and post this proof but you saved me the trouble! ***+1, endorsed!!!***

Comment: This definitely works more nicely than mine! I believe this will also work for any dense set!

Answer (score 2):

Let $ S=\{x\in \Bbb{R} : f(x) =0\}=f^{-1}(\{0\})$

### Since $f$ is continuous, $S\subset \Bbb{R}$ closed.

Claim : $S=\Bbb{R}$

As $f=0$ on $\Bbb{Q}$ , $\Bbb{Q}\subset S$

$\Bbb{Q}\subset S\subset \Bbb{R}$ implies $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}\subset \overline{S}\subset \Bbb{R}$

Hence $\Bbb{R}\subset S\subset \Bbb{R}$ implies $S=\Bbb{R}$ .

Hence $f=0 $ on $\Bbb{R}$.